# How to clone a private gitlab repository without SSH using a token with the new build permissions?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

As of 8.12, cloning using HTTPS + token is not supported anymore, as mentioned here:

> In 8.12 we improved build permissions. Being able to clone project
>   using runners token it is no supported from now on (it was actually
>   working by coincidence and was never a fully fledged feature, so we
>   changed that in 8.12). You should use build token instead.
>
> This is widely documented here -
>   https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html

The previous command to clone a private gitlab repository with a token doesn't work anymore, what's the new recommended way to do it? I know I can use SSH, but I would like to do it with a private/runner token specifically because it's easier for automation scripts.